# how to store multiple DataTables into single DataSet in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

I have the code below which has multiple DataTables with results and I need to pass a single DataSet with all DataTable values.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getLikeInfo, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(getKnowInfo, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);

MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(getHotelInfo, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
da2.Fill(dt2);

MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(getRoomInfo, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
da3.Fill(dt3);

MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(getFoodInfo, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da4 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
da4.Fill(dt4);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
...
```

If you want your tables named in the DataSet you can create your tables from the DataSet

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable t1 = ds.Tables.Add("t1");  // Create
DataTable t1Again = ds.Tables["t1"]; // fetch by name
```

You can also set the `TableName` property of the tables if you use the first approach.