# query the second table with the result of first

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to bind two tables into a dataset. I have three table named, Students, StudentMarks.

Here if I know the studentId I can query the student table like

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE STUDENTID=1; 
SELECT *
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE STUDENTID=1");

SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
```

like this. So that I can access these two tables like ds.Table[0] and ds.Table[1].

But my question is, if I dont know the studentid and if I want to query all the students as well as their marks and I've to get these details in two different tables how can I get?

If I join these two tables, the result will be in a single table, I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me out here? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do after retrieving the result? Getting all Stundets with there corresponding marks, could be done with a JOIN like mrigesh gupta and Mahmoud Gamal suggested you. This would be the normal approch. Why do you want two Datasets?

Comment: @Johannes I need to query the DataTables inside of DataSet like ds.DataTable[0] and ds.DataTable[1], because am using the same format(when I know the student id) in another place

Comment: But why? You can do everything with some simple SQL. Anyway you can run two Querys and add the result in one DataSet see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631286/how-to-store-multiple-datatables-into-single-dataset-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
SELECT
  s.*
FROM STUDENTS s
INNER JOIN StudentMarks m ON s.STUDENTID = m.STUDENTID ;

SELECT
  m.*
FROM STUDENTS s
INNER JOIN StudentMarks m ON s.STUDENTID = m.STUDENTID ;
```

Comment: you just replace S.* with s.<Student_name_field> and M.* with m.<student_marks>

Comment: is it possible to join one more table here? its named StudentAttendance

Comment: yes, you can add another and more. Result depends upon your condition columns. try adding another and check the result.

Comment: @NiranjanKala I tried, but the order is wrong, the above query gives the correct order

Comment: Well, I already said that result depend on the relation and condition column of the these tables that you are joining for the some specific result... go with the answer that suites you better.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to query all the students as well as their marks and I've to
>   get these details in two different tables how can I get?

Why do you want to get the details of two different tables in two different tables?

You can `JOIN` the two tables, but this will give you only one set like so:

```
SELECT
  s.*, 
  m.*
FROM STUDENTS s
INNER JOIN StudentMarks m ON s.STUDENTID = m.STUDENTID ;
-- You can add WHERE s.STUDENTID = 1 here as well;
```

However, you can limit the selection from these joins to `s.*` or `m.*`.

Comment: thanks for ur response, as I said am using DataSet here, so I need to access Students as well as their marks at a time, thats y, so that If I use like ds.Table[0] will give me the Student table and ds.Table[1] will give me the marks of that student

Comment: @Shanish - You can do this using my query. You will have only one `ds.Table[0]` but inside this table you will have something like `Studnetname`, `mark` etc. Then you can select what columns you want to select from this table. You didn't need to have these columns in two different tables in order to select from them seperately.

Comment: thanks Mahmour Gamal, I thought to go for this first, but I just wanted to know that, having two tables will simplify my requirement, anyhow thanks again for ur response

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) Method to get the rows for the studentID you need, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
{
    int studentID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<int>("StudentID");
    DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[1].Select(string.Format("WHERE StudentID = {0}", studentID));
    //Do something with your mark rows here
}
```

Or you could define the relationship within the dataset using [DataRelations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbwcse3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
//Add a primary key to the student table so you can search on StudentID
ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables[0].Columns["StudentID"] };

//Add the relationship between "StudentID" columns in each table
ds.Relations.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns["StudentID"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["StudentID"]);

//Check if the table contains the given StudentID
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Contains(studentID))
{
    //Get all child rows associated with this Student ID
    DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Find(studentID).GetChildRows();
}
```