# Multiple connections with different connection strings

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, connection-string

I will try to be as much clear as possible. The basic info are:
I have four DB on the same server, each DB has a DB version table. 
I'm able to read these by making a connection to one of these DB's 
with only one ConnectionString and getting the result from one big chunk 
of SQL query. These are displayed in datagridview in my WindowsFormsApp. 
The code is as follows:

```
private void FillDataWithGrid()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStrA"].ConnectionString;

        //string ConStringFG = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStrB"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;
        string CmdStrBLM = string.Empty;
        string CmdStrFg = string.Empty;

        DataTable dtBlm = null;

        using (SqlConnection connBLM = new SqlConnection(CmdStrBLM))
        {
            CmdStrBLM =
                "SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(SELECT TOP 1 'DB.A' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime " +
                        "FROM [DB.A].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl1 " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime " +
                        "FROM(SELECT TOP 1  'DB.B' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime " +
                        "FROM [DB.B].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] " +
                        "ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl2 " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(" +
                        "SELECT TOP 1  'DB.C' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime " +
                        "FROM [DB.C].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] " +
                        "ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl3 " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(" +
                        "SELECT TOP 1 'DB.D' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime " +
                        "FROM [DB.D].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] " +
                        "ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl4";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to connect to each of database separately by
its own connection string.

Will this involve multiple connections? If so, then how to handle these with four different connections?

Hope you see my point. Any hints or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you run your own code..? secondly why don't you test the code in sql management studio and see if you get the results that you expect.. if you do.. then I would suggest putting all of that sql code into a storedprocedure then execute the code thus filling that datatable.. also ` DataTable dtBlm = null;` why is this declared if  you are not using it..?

Comment: what are the down votes for?

Comment: the code works for just fine. i'm just struggling with the idea of how to handle the connection multiple times. Also, I cannot do this with SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I manage to get it working. Will post this for future reference. 
I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631286/how-to-store-multiple-datatables-into-single-dataset-in-c).

the solution involves getting data in DataTable format passing in connection string and sqlCommand. Repeat this four times to return DT from each connection. Next create DataSet which will hold all of DT. Create another DT to merge results from DataSet using loop:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(GetData(GetConnectionString(conStringBlm), CmdStrBlm));
//... do this for each connection string 
DataTable dtAll = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
        for (var i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            dtAll.Merge(ds.Tables[i]);
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll;
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do by returning different data tables but I don't see the reason to handle this demand with four different connections to the same DB. It is always better to handle the merge information on DB as your current method. It will be very expensive to get all data from different connections and merge the returning datatable.

Comment: Not to the same DB but to four different dbs.

Comment: It doesn't matter, still same server.