# Split t-sql results into data tables, by non-numerical value in a field

Tags: c#, t-sql

I writing a C# program to output t-SQL records into separate tabs in an excel spreadsheet, split by the person the records belong to.

I have seen that I can have many data tables in a single data set, and turn each into a separate tab ([how to store multiple DataTables into single DataSet in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631286/how-to-store-multiple-datatables-into-single-dataset-in-c)), so now I need to populate my data tables.

I do not have a fixed list of people, it will vary each time the program is run, and a person could have any number of records assigned to them.

Is there a way of doing this using SQL / C# using something like order or group by; or do I have to get my results, pick up the list of people, then loop each SQL query for that specific person and feed that into a new data table?

Thought I'd ask if anyone knew a short way before I did it the long way, because this can't be an uncommon thing to do; so I suspect there must be a simpler way.

Comment: As far as I know, you get one DataTable per SELECT statement. The "long" way is actually not very long code-wise, so unless performance is an issue, I suggest you just go for it.

Comment: Thank you.  Just wanted to check before i spent a day coding then discovered there was a 2 line usual way of doing this.

Comment: Well you could probably just select everything and then use LINQ to group the data and fill your DataTables. Shouldn't take a day ;) See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset) is any help.

Comment: Michal S: If you give this as an answer, I will accept it, because you've answered my question of 'is there a different way'.  thanks for that, i've got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you get one DataTable per SELECT statement.

However, you could just select everything and then use LINQ to group the data and fill your DataTables. See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset) is any help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the table structure, as well as for the source as for the destination.

If you have multiple source tables you can append them together with the UNION statement. Which gives the distinct value of all tables. You can use UNION ALL to keep duplicate values.

```
SELECT customer_key, customer_name, customer_address
```

FROM table_1
WHERE customer_key = @Customer_key

UNION (or UNION ALL)

SELECT customer_key, customer_name, customer_address
FROM table_2
WHERE Customer_key = @Customer_key

UNION etc..