# C# - DataTable within a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, blueprism

In Blue Prism (BP), there is something called a Collection, which is basically a DataTable in C#. In BP, you can have a Collection within a Collection. My question is, can you have a DataTable within a DataTable in C#?

Here is my code below:

```
//inner datatable
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("TestOne");
DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("TestTwo");
dt2.Columns.Add(dc5);
dt2.Columns.Add(dc6);
dt2.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2");

//outer datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Age");
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Gender");
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("InnerDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

//adding of inner datatable to outer datatable
dt.Rows.Add("John", "23", "Male", dt2);
dt.Rows.Add("Gretchen", "25", "Female", dt2);
dt.Rows.Add("Jordan", "28", "Male", dt2);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
string xml = ds.GetXml();
Console.WriteLine(xml);
Console.ReadLine();
```

At the end, I am parsing the DataSet into an XML but the InnerDataTable column does not have any value. Is there something I am doing wrong here or is this simply not possible in C#?

This is the output ***I want*** in Console:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable>
      <TestOne>Value1</TestOne>
      <TestTwo>Value2</TestTwo>
    </InnerDataTable>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Name>Gretchen</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable>
      <TestOne>Value1<TestOne>
      <TestTwo>Value2</TestTwo>
    </InnerDataTable>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Name>Jordan</Name>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable>
      <TestOne>Value1<TestOne>
      <TestTwo>Value2</TestTwo>
    </InnerDataTable>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

But this is ***what is actually shown***:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable />
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Name>Gretchen</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable />
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Name>Jordan</Name>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <InnerDataTable />
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: add each table to your dataset, not to another datatable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631286/how-to-store-multiple-datatables-into-single-dataset-in-c

Comment: @MitchWheat so I can't add a datatable in another datatable's column?

Comment: I think this documentation on the DataColumn will help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @thecodeexplorer, take a look at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hJcT8H. It's not exactly what your looking for, but it does nest the inner data table inside your dataset. The difference is that the inner datatable has a TableName property set and the DataColumn containing the inner datatable has it's DataType set to typeof(DataTable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within your code that defines the schema of the DataTable, specifically where you define the column for *InnerDataTable*.

```
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("InnerDataTable");
```

The [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumn__ctor_System_String_) initializes the instance of `DataColumn` class, as type string. If you want the type to be `DataTable`, then you want the type to be of `typeof(DataTable)`.

```
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("InnerDataTable", typeof(DataTable));
```

However, defining *InnerDataTable* as a `DataTable` type will not get the output you are expecting. You will need to define a class to model the *InnerDataTable*.

```
public class InnerTable
{
    public string TestOne { get; set; }
    public string TestTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And then define *InnerDataTable* column of `typeof(InnerTable)`.

```
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("InnerDataTable", typeof(InnerTable));
```

I have put up the full solution at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XR14xL).

Comment: thank you for explaining this to me. so I guess if I plan to do this approach, then I would have to make a class for each inner datatable.